# Htaccess issue with installing php script in WordPress directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My root directory has a wordpress install in it.  I added a folder called 'jobs' and put a php script in it.  When I access mysite.com/jobs, it works.. but when I drill down below that, such as trying to access mysite.com/jobs/parttime/miami   -- that's when it defaults to the wordpress 404 page.

I've been searching for the right answer here, but can't seem to make anything work.

.htaccess

```
 # BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteRule ^jobs - [L] 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What does your `.htaccess` file look like. You probably need to add a separate rule for your `/jobs` directory and exclude that directory from the Wordpress rewrites.

Comment: This could also be a question for ServerFault...

Comment: Thx Jeroen.  I kept trying to post the code but couldn't get it to format.

Comment: If you remove your htaccess file, and go to `http://mysite.com/jobs/parttime/miami`, you don't get a 404?

Comment: Yes.. anything past the jobs/ directory gives the 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to go around solving this. An alternative would be add a RewriteCond to the main WordPress redirect, so that it skips requests beginning with jobs.

```
 # BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?jobs
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```

Comment: I still can't seem to make it work, but I'm sure your code is right and something else is going on.. so I'll give you a best answer.  :)  thanks for the assistance!